# How to create xls sheet and add dynamic data into it in Android?

Tags: android

This my code and I want to add data I got from an `EditText` each time dynamically.

```
//New Workbook
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

Cell c = null;

//Cell style for header row
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

//New Sheet
Sheet sheet1 = null;
sheet1 = wb.createSheet("MYtest");

// Generate column headings
Row row1=sheet1.createRow(0);
c = row1.createCell(0);
c.setCellValue("ENTRY ONE");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row1.createCell(1);
c.setCellValue("ENTRY TWO");
c.setCellStyle(cs);

c = row1.createCell(2);
c.setCellValue("ENTRY THREE");
c.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Comment: You should subdivide or narrow your question. Is your problem the creation of an XLS-file or the construction of an Android GUI to retrieve user input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a cell value with the data that you entered in an `EditText` dynamically, you should use a `TextWatcher to set the text in the cell. See example below:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        row1.getCell(1).setCellValue(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Although, depending on how you visualise the XLS file, the change can't be considered dynamic since you have to export the document and then view it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **apache POI**.
Download apache POI jar file or

add line into the gradle file.

```
 compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
```

And create, read, write excel file.

below is the sample tutorial for your reference [click here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html)